# Pick the matching result between 2 lists using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists:

List 1:

```
[
{
"TPN": "AL M",
"IL": [
  {
    "PIN": 1502103214,
    "Suffix": null
  }
]
},
{
"TPN": "ABC",
"IL": [
  {
    "PIN": 6509507561,
    "Suffix": null
  },
  {
    "PIN": 1234056789,
    "Suffix": null
  }

]
},
{
"TPN": "XYZ",
"IL": [
  {
    "PIN": 7507668878,
    "Suffix": null
  }
]
}
]
```

List 2:

```
List<decimal> list2 = new List<decimal>(){ 6509507561, 7507668878 }
```

I want to filter List 1 based on the List 2 values.
So my final list should be

```
[
  {
    "TPN": "ABC",
    "IL": [
       {
         "PIN": 6509507561,
         "Suffix": null
       }
     ]
  },
  {
    "TPN": "XYZ",
    "IL": [
       {
        "PIN": 7507668878,
        "Suffix": null
       }
     ]
   }
]
```

The LINQ query I am using is:

```
var indInfoTemp = list1.Where(ind => ind.IL.All(x => list2.Any(y => y == x.PIN)))
                       .ToList();
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with this query.

Thanks,
Sajesh

Comment: you don't need .All. Just do
indInfoTemp = list1.Where(x => list2.Any(y => y == x.PIN)).ToList();

Comment: I think your use of All is most likely the problem - but I think it would be better to use Join for this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether `IL` contains the PIN and then filter `IL` using a select by the PIN.

```
var indInfoTemp = list1.Where(ind => ind.IL.Any(il => list2.Contains(il.PIN)))
                       .Select(ind => new { 
                                 ind.TPN, 
                                 IL = ind.IL.Where(il => list2.Contains(il.PIN))
                                            .ToList()
                         })
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Avin and Bloodday, yes this worked correctly, making this as answered

Comment: Note,  use whatever type you have, I have used an anonymous type because I do not know your types

Answer (score 1):

Any returns `bool` so you are using a the all function with that bool

if you want to select only the values of list 1 that are contained in list2 use `.contains` like this:

```
indInfoTemp = list1.Where(ind => list2.Contains(ind.IL[0].PIN)).ToList();
```

Comment: i tried this but still zero record.  indInfoTemp = list1
                            .Where(ind => list2.Contains(ind.IL.FirstOrDefault().PIN)).ToList();

Comment: No the structure is the same both are decimal, indInfoTemp = list1 .Where(ind => list2.Contains(ind.IL.Select(x=>x.PIN).FirstOrDefault())).ToList(); still zero record

Comment: break the query appart, and check if the FirstOrDefault method is returning something

Comment: This will not filter the inner list `IL`

Answer (score 1):

you can use an extension like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool In<T>(T input, params T[] list) => list.Any(item => item.Equals(input));
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var indInfoTemp = list1.Where(ind => ind.IL.PIN.In(list2.ToArray())).ToList();
```